# String and variables won't concatenate on same line

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

I am unable to print the serial number and definition of a word on the same line using below code. Any advice would be much appreciated. I've read through previously asked Q&A on this but no luck.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests

loops = ""

while loops == "":

    url = "http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/"

    c = 1
    word = input("Enter word (0 to quit): ")
    if word == "0":
        break
    data = requests.get(url + word)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(data.text, "html.parser")

    data1 = soup.find_all("div",{"class":"def-content"})

    print("The meaning/s of " + word + " is/are:")

    for i in data1:
        if i.string != None:
            print(c, i.string)  # Trying to print serial number and definition on same line
            c = c + 1
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? Or on what is your output different from what you were expecting?

Comment: No error, I just want the two components of my output, (i) the serial number  and (ii) the word meaning, to appear on the same line but I get "1" and then the meaning of the word on the next line, and "2" in the third line, and the second meaning on the 4th line and so on.  Thanks.

Comment: So your `i.string` contains `\n` at the beginning. What a big deal. Try using `stripped_string` instead if it doesn't suit your needs...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
        print(str(c)+ " " + i.string.strip('\n'))
```

Comment: You probably just want `.strip()`

Comment: No, I mean literally as I've shown it - `str.strip` with no arguments removes all whitespace characters, including `'\n'`, by default.

Comment: Does he want to remove all leading and trailing whitespace characters or just newlines?

Comment: In general, it's easiest to remove it all then put back in only what (if anything) you need with `str.join` or `str.format`.

Comment: Bingo! Thanks akoinesjr. Just wanted to remove new lines.

Comment: @ks3000 They both "work" but they do different things. The strip method removes all leading and trailing whitespace characters including newlines by default with no arguments, so if that is what you want to do, call strip without passing anything in. If you want to remove only newlines but leave in other whitespace characters, then pass in \n. https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html